# UnauthorizedAccessException while trying to rename file

Tags: c#, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm trying to create a program that generates random file prefixes and renames all files in a directory. It runs perfectly fine in most cases, but after multiple successful tests, I sometimes encountered a strange **UnauthorizedAccessException**. For example, the exception is thrown every time the directory is located on the desktop. Weirdly, there are also cases in which the renaming process is successful, but after trying it again in the *same* directory (after restoring the old file names; so like a fresh start), the exception is thrown.
This is how I try to rename the files:

```
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);      
    int max = files.Length, success = 0;

    foreach (var filePath in files) {
        var file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        var prefix = GenerateRandomPrefix(_runtimeSettings.Pattern, _runtimeSettings.CharList, _runtimeSettings.ReplacementLength);
        var renamedFile = filePath.Replace(file, string.Concat(prefix, file));

        try {
            File.Move(filePath, renamedFile);
            success++;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I've already checked multiple things, like if the directory or any file is read-only. I've also tried running in administrator mode, but to my surprise, not even that fixes the occurrence of the UnauthorizedAccessException. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-7.0) of File.Move(), it explicitly says:

> UnauthorizedAccessException: The caller does not have the required permission.

So at least running in administrator should fix the error, but why does it persist?

Comment: File permissions in Windows are a lot more complicated than simply being the administrator. Can you rename the file manually? However, it's very hard to tell from the information provided what the actual issue is.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, manually renaming is no problem at all. The strangest thing is that it generally works fine, but there are some cases where it does not work (e.g., on the desktop it never works)

Comment: It could well be that the file is in use by the program that is running the test. You need to look at the actual exception. Note that you are suppressing exceptions and returning within the loop. You should at least observe the exception for debugging purposes

Comment: @AluanHaddad I know, and I didn't show it, but actually, I do not suppress the exception and instead log it exactly for debugging purposes, but it isn't helpful since it just points to the call of File.Move(). I'm now figuring out if the file may be currently in use, but considering that it works most of the time, I don't think that's the problem.